# How can I modify the bottom margin in clean thesis?

Tags: margins, cleanthesis

I am using [clean thesis template](http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/) v0.4.0.

I would like to know how to modify the height of the footer.
The default setting seems to have a huge margin.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `cleanthesis.sty` file contained in the .zip from your link, the relevant code is here:

```
\setlength{\footheight}{120pt}      % avoids scrlayer-scrpage warning:
                                    % footheight to low warning
\setlength{\footskip}{185pt}        % BAD HACK that moves the foot downwards
```

Modifying these and loading the `geometry` package to change the page margins (I could not see where the margin was being defined to give such a gap) gives this:

[image][image]

Add these lines:

```
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\footheight}{20pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{60pt}
```

after:

```
% **************************************************
% Setup YOUR thesis document in this file !
% **************************************************
\input{my-thesis-setup}
```

in the `my-thesis.tex` file and play with the numbers and margins. Those are the values used to replicate the pictures I have uploaded. The `geometry` package [has good documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) and you can modify it via `top`, `bottom` etc. and change the values of `\footheight` and `\footskip` until you are happy with it. This works but is likely not the greatest solution.

Comment: Thank you! You saved my Ph.D. thesis. What I wanted is `\usepackage[bottom=2cm]{geometry} `